# mapbox maps in android

Tags: android, mapbox

I am developing a navigation app in android. i want to have the maps downloaded on first launch and made available offline.

This code here has troubled me a little.

```
mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {



@Override
public  void onMapReady(MapboxMap mapboxMap) {
```

it brings an error:

> Class 'Anonymous class derived from OnMapReadyCallback' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'onMapReady(GoogleMap)' in 'OnMapReadyCallback'

I dont wish to implement abstract method 'onMapReady(GoogleMap)' since i'm using MapBox maps instead.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you check my answer?

Answer (score 1):

> Class 'Anonymous class derived from OnMapReadyCallback' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'onMapReady(GoogleMap)' in 'OnMapReadyCallback'

This error indicates that you're using `OnMapReadyCallback` from the Google SDK, not from the Mapbox SDK. Make sure your import looks like this:

```
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your imports on this Activity/fragment, If you're using this

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
```

Use Should use this:

```
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.Mapbox;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapboxMap;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
```

and your layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:mapbox="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".examples.MapViewActivity">

    <!-- Set the starting camera position and map style using xml-->
    <com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        mapbox:mapbox_cameraTargetLat="40.73581"
        mapbox:mapbox_cameraTargetLng="-73.99155"
        mapbox:mapbox_styleUrl="@string/mapbox_style_mapbox_streets"
        mapbox:mapbox_cameraZoom="11"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope it helps !!

Comment: I had to resolve it by separating the mainactivity from the mapbox activity. that solved the issue